# RouterModule component, loadChildren, redirectTo

Tags: angular

Could anybody tell me the difference between `component`, `loadChildren`, `redirectTo`?

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
   path: '', redirectTo: 'signin', pathMatch: 'full'
  }, {
    path: 'app',   loadChildren: () => System.import('./layout/layout.module')
  }, {
    path: 'login', loadChildren: () => System.import('./login/login.module')
  }, {
    path: 'signin', loadChildren: () => System.import('./signin/signin.module')
  }, {
    path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent
  }, {
    path: '**',    component: ErrorComponent
  }
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the documentation can do it. Check the [router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) page.

Otherwise, `component` is to directly link a path to a `component`, `loadChildren` is used to load `asynchronous component` and `redirectTo` is simply to redirect to another route.

Comment: `loadChildren` is used to load `components` or `modules`?

Comment: It's for module indeed, loadChildren have a special syntax. `loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'` where you specify the file and the class. But once again, please check the documentation.

Comment: That better fits in your answer than a comment @Sakuto

Answer (score 1):

**component** => A string that acts as a URL for a single route.

**redirectTo** => Same like component i.e. URL for a single route. Used to redirect URL if available, or use the default URL.

**loadChildren** => A string that acts as a URL for a *set of routes* to load, or a function that returns such a set.

Answer (score 1):

`component` will load all components when the app loads

`loadChildren` is used for lazy loading

> By default, NgModules are eagerly loaded, which means that as soon as
> the app loads, so do all the NgModules, whether or not they are
> immediately necessary. For large apps with lots of routes, consider
> lazy loading—a design pattern that loads NgModules as needed. Lazy
> loading helps keep initial bundle sizes smaller, which in turn helps
> decrease load times.

[More about angular lazy loading.](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)